# Google-Apps-Script Non-Cloud Database Connection Options

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, google-apps-script

Is there any way to link a google-docs-spreadsheet with a database that is not in the cloud?

Client has a very complex google-doc that they do not want to re-develop but want to make it multi-user with a common data repository.

The ideal solution would be to link it to a standard SQL database.  If anyone out there can provide a way to do that I would be very grateful.

I understand that JDBC in google-apps-script can only connect to a database in the cloud which client may struggle with.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for the database to be in the cloud. You can have a single instance database accepting JDBC connections over the internet. [Google even tells you what IP addresses are used](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#accessing) to connect to the database so that you can put this filter on the listening port of your database.

You can use the [JDBCService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_jdbc) of Google Apps Script to achieve this

Comment: I have found that using stored procedures and JDBC simplifies things quite a but. I have created some libraries for making this easier in spreadsheet. Let me know if you would like to get the code.